# UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan 0. 0.] when running HalvingRandomSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am trying to search for optimal parameters by using the faster version of RandomizedSearchCV--->HalvingRandomSearchCV class from sklearn. My dataset is large (~1million records), it has 10 classes and it is imbalanced.

My code looks like this:

```
# Define parameters for model 
params_cat = {'loss_function': 'MultiClass',  
              'eval_metric': 'AUC',
              'random_state': seed,
              'iterations': 20000,
              'early_stopping_rounds' : 5000}

# Define Parameters for Grid 
params_grid = {'max_depth': [8, 10],
               'l2_leaf_reg': [3, 5], #5, 10, 15
               # 'random_strength' : [3], #5
               # 'border_count': [128], #254
               #'iterations': [20000, 30000] #40000 }

cat = CatBoostClassifier(**params_cat)


mcc_scorer = make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef) cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.01, random_state=42) gridsearch = HalvingRandomSearchCV(cat, params_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, verbose=3,
                                   scoring=mcc_scorer, return_train_score = True)

gridsearch.fit(X_train_val, y_train_val)
```

When running it, I get the following error:

```
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:873: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
[CV 1/2] END l2_leaf_reg=5, max_depth=9;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.000) total time= 6.0min
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:873: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
[CV 2/2] END l2_leaf_reg=5, max_depth=9;, score=(train=1.000, test=0.000) total time= 6.0min
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:925: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan  0.  0.]
  category=UserWarning
```

I don't understand whether the cause of the error is the HalvingRandomSearchCV, the scorer I'm using or the values for the parameters. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thank you!